# How to put a image div right next to a text div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the GTA Online Tips loading screen in HTML.

This is what I'm trying to make - http://prntscr.com/6n7txe
This is what I have - http://prntscr.com/6n7w92

The problem im focusing on right now is to get the 2 dives rightnext to each other with the right width and height.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GTA ONLINE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="text">
        <p class="top">GTA Online</p>
        <p class="middle">First Person Mode</p>
        <p class="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu adipiscing elit. Maecenas sodales, velit sed dictum fermentum, ligula nunc  sodales magna, at convallis. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="pics/Trevor.jpg"
    </div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url("../pics/background_1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.column {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.column .picture img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}

.column .text {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}

.column .text p{
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: May not be relevant to your problem, but you're not closing the image tag.

Comment: Float the `.text` class and the `.picture` class left. They will bump up to each other. Add `overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto;` to the `.column` class so that it contains both the text and picture elements properly and it center aligned on the page.

Comment: there is a nice guide on how to have an image on any side with text-- http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/insert-images-website/align-float-images-css  -. If its going on top of another image use position absolute and with a higher z-index value. demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/gufLx9rn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

omit **float:right** and **float:left** but add **display:inline-block** to both divs.

```
    body{
        background-image: url("../pics/background_1.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .column {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .column .picture img {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: right;

    }

   /* new style start*/
    .column .picture {
    display:inline-block;
    }
   /* also set width to this div 
      otherwise it takes 100% and won't 
      stay inline with other elements.
      new style end */ 

    .column .text {
        background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width:50%;
    }

    .column .text p{
        color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        width:50%;
    }
```

Comment: there are white text that overflowed text div that might make sense that it doesn't work.

Comment: this will work fine if **white-space: nowrap;** is removed from **.column** (I don't know what that stands for?) and also set a width to .picture div otherwise it will take 100% width (Edited in reply).

Answer (score 2):

```css
.column{float:left;width:100%;}
.text{float:left;width:48%;margin-right:2%;}
.picture{float:left;width:50%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a few unclosed elements in your HTML - the first `<div>` in the `body` has no matching closing complement `</div>` and the `img` with Trevor is missing the ending bracket **`>`**. (It is also missing a required atrribute `alt` so ideally, it should look something like `<img src="pics/Trevor.jpg" alt="Trevor" />`.

Now to the point. It is rather simple, both `div`s need to be floated to the `left`, so in your `.column .picture img`, just replace `float: right;` with `float:left`, that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background-image: url("../pics/background_1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.column {
width:100%;/* you can give 1000px also */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.column .picture img {
    width: 50%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.column .text {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}

.column .text p{
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    width:100%;
}
```